# Get the newest data from sql but not working

Tags: php, sql

I would like to get the newest comments in following code, but now only showing the oldest 50 comments, how can I edit code to showing the newest 50 comments? thanks so much

[Code here:](http://pastebin.com/NaW4BX22)

```
<?php


class comments extends db_connect
{

        private $requestFrom = 0;
    private $language = 'en';

        public function __construct($dbo = NULL)
    {
                parent::__construct($dbo);
        }

    public function allCommentsCount()
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT max(id) FROM comments");
        $stmt->execute();

        return $number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    }

    public function count($postId)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE postId = (:postId) AND removeAt = 0");
        $stmt->bindParam(":postId", $postId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    }

    public function create($postId, $text, $notifyId = 0)
    {
        $result = array("error" => true,
                        "error_code" => ERROR_UNKNOWN);

        if (strlen($text) == 0) {

            return $result;
        }

        $post = new post($this->db);

        $postInfo = $post->info($postId);

        unset($post);

        $currentTime = time();
        $ip_addr = helper::ip_addr();
        $u_agent = helper::u_agent();

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (fromUserId, postId, comment, createAt, notifyId, ip_addr, u_agent) value (:fromUserId, :postId, :comment, :createAt, :notifyId, :ip_addr, :u_agent)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":fromUserId", $this->requestFrom, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":postId", $postId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":comment", $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":createAt", $currentTime, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":notifyId", $notifyId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ip_addr", $ip_addr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":u_agent", $u_agent, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            $result = array("error" => false,
                            "error_code" => ERROR_SUCCESS,
                            "commentId" => $this->db->lastInsertId(),
                            "comment" => $this->info($this->db->lastInsertId()));

            if ($this->requestFrom != $postInfo['fromUserId']) {

                $gcm = new gcm($this->db, $postInfo['fromUserId']);
                $gcm->setData(GCM_NOTIFY_COMMENT, "You have a new comment.", $postId);
                $gcm->send();
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function remove($commentId)
    {
        $result = array("error" => true,
                        "error_code" => ERROR_UNKNOWN);

        $commentInfo = $this->info($commentId);

        if ($commentInfo['error'] === true) {

            return $result;
        }

//        if ($commentInfo['fromUserId'] != $this->requestFrom) {
//
//            return $result;
//        }

        $currentTime = time();

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE comments SET removeAt = (:removeAt) WHERE id = (:commentId)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":commentId", $commentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":removeAt", $currentTime, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            $result = array("error" => false,
                            "error_code" => ERROR_SUCCESS);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function removeAll($postId) {

        $currentTime = time();

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE comments SET removeAt = (:removeAt) WHERE postId = (:postId)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":postId", $postId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":removeAt", $currentTime, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }

    public function info($commentId)
    {
        $result = array("error" => true,
                        "error_code" => ERROR_UNKNOWN);

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = (:commentId) LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bindParam(":commentId", $commentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

                $row = $stmt->fetch();

                $time = new language($this->db, $this->language);

                $profile = new profile($this->db, $row['fromUserId']);
                $fromUserId = $profile->get();
                unset($profile);

                $lowPhotoUrl = "/img/profile_default_photo.png";

                if (strlen($fromUserId['lowPhotoUrl']) != 0) {

                    $lowPhotoUrl = $fromUserId['lowPhotoUrl'];
                }

                $post = new post($this->db);
                $post->setRequestFrom($this->getRequestFrom());

                $postInfo = $post->info($row['postId']);

                $result = array("error" => false,
                                "error_code" => ERROR_SUCCESS,
                                "id" => $row['id'],
                                "fromUserId" => $row['fromUserId'],
                                "fromUserState" => $fromUserId['state'],
                                "fromUserUsername" => $fromUserId['username'],
                                "fromUserFullname" => $fromUserId['fullname'],
                                "fromUserPhotoUrl" => $lowPhotoUrl,
                                "postId" => $row['postId'],
                                "postFromUserId" => $postInfo['fromUserId'],
                                "comment" => htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['comment'])),
                                "createAt" => $row['createAt'],
                                "notifyId" => $row['notifyId'],
                                "timeAgo" => $time->timeAgo($row['createAt']));
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function get($postId, $commentId = 0)
    {
        if ($commentId == 0) {

            $commentId = $this->allCommentsCount() + 1;
        }

        $comments = array("error" => false,
                         "error_code" => ERROR_SUCCESS,
                         "commentId" => $commentId,
                         "postId" => $postId,
                         "comments" => array());

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM comments WHERE postId = (:postId) AND id < (:commentId) AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,38");
        $stmt->bindParam(':postId', $postId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':commentId', $commentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

                $commentInfo = $this->info($row['id']);

                array_push($comments['comments'], $commentInfo);

                $comments['commentId'] = $commentInfo['id'];

                unset($commentInfo);
            }
        }

        return $comments;
    }

    public function getPreview($postId)
    {
        $commentId = $this->allCommentsCount() + 1;

        $comments = array("error" => false,
                          "error_code" => ERROR_SUCCESS,
                          "commentId" => $commentId,
                          "postId" => $postId,
                          "count" => $this->count($postId),
                          "comments" => array());

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM comments WHERE postId = (:postId) AND id < (:commentId) AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3");
        $stmt->bindParam(':postId', $postId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':commentId', $commentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

                $commentInfo = $this->info($row['id']);

                array_push($comments['comments'], $commentInfo);

                $comments['commentId'] = $commentInfo['id'];

                unset($commentInfo);
            }
        }

        return $comments;
    }

    public function setLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->language = $language;
    }

    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    public function setRequestFrom($requestFrom)
    {
        $this->requestFrom = $requestFrom;
    }

    public function getRequestFrom()
    {
        return $this->requestFrom;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you give your select statement and your table structure info, people may help you better, instead of reviewing your all code

Comment: thx.. I think this code... whats wrong with my code?                                                                                                    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM comments WHERE postId = (:postId) AND id < (:commentId) AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,38");

Comment: what happens when you change the order by clause with `ORDER BY id DESC` ?

Comment: it will changed to showing the oldest comments from first to No. 38 posts.

Comment: if you have a column whose type is`timestamp` in your table use that to sort

Comment: it will changed to showing the oldest comments from first to No. 38 comment, if ASC, it will only show 38 comments from the no.38 comment to no.1 comment.  for example, there are 50 comments now, It will showing 38 comments from the no.38 comment to no.1 comment. but  want to showing the newest 38 comments, that should be showing 38 comments from No. 50 to No.12 ..

Comment: sorry , can tell me more ?? thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `LIMIT` from `LIMIT 0,38` to `LIMIT 38`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your code: why does it works? What should it do?

Comment: try to run query `SELECT id FROM comments WHERE postId = (:postId) AND id < (:commentId) AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,38` and check the result, is it correct? I tried some queries on my database, and got correct results.

Comment: it can got results.. but just : it will changed to showing the oldest comments from first to No. 38 comment, if ASC, it will only show 38 comments from the no.38 comment to no.1 comment. for example, there are 50 comments now, It will showing 38 comments from the no.38 comment to no.1 comment. but want to showing the newest 38 comments, that should be showing 38 comments from No. 50 to No.12

Comment: Even, if you running this query from MYSQL (phpMyAdmin for example)? Try to run query without LIMIT. Could you also post your table data?

Comment: if run it without limit, it will loading so slow

Comment: If there is 50 records only, select should not be slow.... Colud you show table structure?